# Is there a Python subprocess-like call that takes a stdin input string and returns stderr, stdout, and return code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

As per the subject line, is there a standard Python 2.7 library call that I can use like this:

```
(returncode, stdout, stderr) = invoke_subprocess(args, stdin)
```

The catch is that I want all three forms of output:  the returncode and the entire (and separate) content from both stdout and stderr.  I expected to find something like this in the subprocess module, but the closest I can see is `subprocess.check_output`, which gives you two out of three (the returncode and stdout).

There are other questions on stack overflow that suggest piping stderr to stdout, but I need to keep them separate because I'm using Python to drive testing of some non-Python applications where I'm trying to distinguish which output shows up on which streams.  For example, I want to verify that human-readable error messages shows up in stderr, but that only machine-parseable output data shows up on stdout.

I think what I want is a simple four-liner...

```
def method(args, input):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate(input)
    return (p.poll(), out, err)
```

...so I'm a bit surprised that there's not already be a method like this, given the number of other methods that are *mostly* similar to this in the `subprocess` module.  Does it exist and I'm missing it, or is it present somewhere in some other standard Python 2.7 module?  Or is there a subtle reason why a method like this is a bad idea?

Comment: "I think what I want is a simple four-liner ... so I'm a bit surprised that there's not already a method like this..." -- As you said, it's a simple 4-liner.  Generally, I'm not surprised if I have to write 4 lines of code to do something... :)  Although, FWIW, I'd use `p.returncode` rather than `p.poll()` since `returncode` is also set by `Popen.communicate`.

Comment: In Python 3.5 and up, use `subprocess.run()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't exist because that's what `subprocess.Popen` is designed to do. The other functions exist mostly to support drop-in replacement of `os.system` and common simplistic automation cases. Trying to cover every use case with a one-liner would result in an even more bloated set of functions.

Also note that you can use `p.returncode` rather than `p.poll()`. It's guaranteed to have been set by the time `p.communicate(...)` returns.

Comment: Accepting this as the closest answer, although it still seems to me that such a function would be the opposite of code bloat:  longer methods in subprocess could be removed and/or be more concisely expressed as in terms of a method like this.  (For example, `def call(*args, **kwargs): return method(*args, **kwargs)[0]`.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use os.system(cmd) which return returncode of command.

Comment: Since the `os.system()` documentation specifically says that using the methods in the `subprocess` module is preferable *and* since the question specifically asks for something that returns stderr and stdout (neither of which is returned by `os.system()`), this is not a suitable answer.

Comment: Yes you can prefer subprocess instead of os.system() but if command is small and only need to get error returncode then use os.system().